# Vector field and real numbers

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

In a undergraduate text for linear algebra, the author writes a function

$F: \boldsymbol{V} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{2}$

where V is a vector space, and the author doesn't provide a mathematical formulation of this function. 
The chapter in question is about the isomorphism beetween vectors and arrays of real numbers.

My question is : since  $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ is a vector field itself, what's the meaning in  defining a function  $\boldsymbol{V} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{2}$ ???

Comment: I don't understand your question. What's wrong with having a function from a vector space $V$ to $\Bbb R^2$?

Comment: If $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ is a vector space, what's the difference beetween $\boldsymbol{V}$ and $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ ?

Comment: There's more than one vector space. Almost surely $V$ is different from $\Bbb R^2$ if you take an arbitrary vector space $V$.

Comment: What if $V$ were $\Bbb R^3$ for instance?

Comment: And even if $V=\mathbb{R}^3$ there are lots of different functions - even lots of different linear maps - from $V$ to $\mathbb{R}^3$. (E.g. the identity map is different from the projection map $(x, y, z)\mapsto (x, 0, 0)$ is different from the rotation map $(x, y, z)\mapsto (x, z, y)$ ...)

Comment: So V simply represents a generic vector space ?

Comment: $\mathbb R^2$ is not a vector field. Vector field means something entirely different from vector _space_.

Answer (score 0):

The meaning is that $V$ is any vector space (it can be $\mathbb R^k$ for some $k$, a vector space of polyomials or functions, or matrices, or whatever) and you are mapping that vector space into the specific vector space $\mathbb R^2$.

$F$ need not be any linear or simple function, it simply takes an element of $V$ and outputs an element of $\mathbb R^2$. For instance, if $V$ is the set of polynomials with real coefficients of degree 2, then for instance $F$ can be such that
$$F:a+bX\mapsto(a+b,a-b),$$
which is actually an isomorphism.